# video live with hls, how to use video tag making continue play when the stream recover from interrupted?

Tags: html, video, live, http-live-streaming

we are developing live product， the audience are use video tag of html5 to watch，so server end to client end is using hls protocol， now， i have a question: when the anchor publish stream is interrupted， video of the audience end also stoped, when the anchor recover, continue to publish stream, how to let the video of audience auto continus to play, current situation is must manual refresh the page，I'm sorry for my statements because of my poor english， please help me， brother and sister！

Comment: if the stream has been interrupted and the user has received an error in the video playback, then I'd suggest your code fire a timer than checks for the stream playing again every few seconds and then adjusts the currentTime to match (but I don't have a setup that would let me check that easily)

Comment: the user end can't received an error when the stream has been interrupted, just stop there with the last frame， so I was wondering if there is a function that the video tag can recognize the stream is working or interrupted? thanks

Comment: are you watching the 'error' event from the video object - https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html